# On lable focus enter press to raise event

Tags: vb.net, events, focus, label, enter

I'm trying to get this sub to execute when my lable has focus and someone clicks "Enter"  This is the code I have so far...

```
Private Sub AssignOwnersLabel_Click() Handles AssignOwnersLabel.Click
    Dim repository As OwnerRepositorySvc.OwnerRepositoryClient = Nothing

    For Each programRow As DataGridViewRow In ProgramOwnerFill.SelectedRows
        programRow.Cells(0).Value = AssignOwnersTXTBox.Text
    Next

    repository = OpenRepository()
    repository.SaveOwners(_ds)
    _ds.AcceptChanges()
    CloseRepository(repository)

    Dim dataview As DataView = _ds.ProgramOwners.DefaultView

    dataview.Sort = _ds.ProgramOwners.EmployeeIDColumn.ColumnName
    Me.ProgramOwnersBindingSource.DataSource = dataview

End Sub
```

I think to get this to work I need to do something with "keychar" but I'm not sure how that would look.  Thanks for help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To find out if the user pressed the enter key, do this:

```
Private Sub Form1_KeyPress(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.KeyPressEventArgs) Handles Me.KeyPress
    If e.KeyCode = Keys.Enter Then
        ' Put logic here for when the user pressed enter
    End if
End Sub
```

Note: There are several key-type events, such as `KeyPress`, `KeyDown` and `KeyUp`.

Comment: I'm not passing e anywhere in the sub the way it is now.  Should I be doing this on the form.load event then?  Or create a new sub to handle my : AssignOwnersLabel.Click event?

Comment: Ah, my fault, I have updated my answer to show the event that generates the `e` event argument.